# Is it better to learn windows forms or WPF knowing that i will be using syncfusion to make my UI controls?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, cross-platform, syncfusion

The project is directed to provide finance based solutions (specially concerning stocks). 
for back end the technologies i am planning to learn and use are web C# based web API and SQL server for database. which is best to use as a webAPI  asp.net or core or mvc for my api?
bonus questions: since i am learning these technologies, is it better to learn a cross platform based frameworks like react-native and xamarin. and which do you think is best platform that generates mobile apps in addition to windows application, if performance is a key factor?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, WinForm is much simpler than WPF to learn, but WPF is way more powerful and flexible (in my opinion). So I suggest to start directly by learning WPF.

CrossPlatform frameworks like xamarin are good way to rapidly deploy solutions in all platforms. But, if you're creating custom views, you'll have to create a custom view for each platform anyway.

Xamarin.Forms (cross-platform) is much slower than using the native language of each platform.

Last thing, if you want to deploy your app for Windows + Android + iOS, you should use Xamarin.Forms, it's pretty similar to WPF and it gives you some UI elements to share with each platform (Labels, Switchs, StackLayout, ...) and all the libraries that C# can give you, while it stays outside of native code.

Hope this helps, 
All the best.

Comment: I do not agree with everything stated in your answer. You can create custom views/controls by extending XamarinForms existing views without having the need to implement custom renderer for each platform. Of course, if your control must have very specific behavior, then, as every framework, you would perhaps need to write the control for every platform, but for now, xamarin offers a lot of built-in features that you can extend for many common and complex usages. 
Of course, XF is slower than native language, but I won't say much slower, its perf are great today as of version 3.0.